# Destroying Rancher2_Cluster with terraform is failing due to aks resources in "deleting" state

Tags: terraform, azure-aks, terraform-provider-azure, rancher, azure-application-gateway

We're facing an issue in terraform in combination with Rancher2 and AKS. We're using terraform to deploy a **rancher2_cluster** with an aks config also creating a new subnet.

while trying to destroy everything, we run into an issue, where the **azurerm_subnet** is still in use by the cluster node in azure. therefore it can't be deleted.

`Message="Subnet subnet_name is in use by /subscriptions/xxx-xx-xx-xx-xxx/resourceGroups/MC_cluster-resource-group-name_location/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/aks-node-id-nic-0/ipConfigurations/ipconfig1 and cannot be deleted. In order to delete the subnet, delete all the resources within the subnet. See aka.ms/deletesubnet." Details=[]`

If we run terraform destroy, after we checked that everything related to the aks cluster is destroyed on the azure side, the subnet gets deleted.

We tried using **rancher2_sync**. but it has no effect so far. Is there any other way to achieve the smooth deletion of every resource we have used?

As a last resort, I see the way of implementing a sleep before destroy, which wouldn't be that nice in my opinion

```
# This resource will destroy (at least) 30 seconds after null_resource.next
resource "null_resource" "previous" {}

resource "time_sleep" "wait_30_seconds" {
  depends_on = [null_resource.previous]

  destroy_duration = "30s"
}

# This resource will create (potentially immediately) after null_resource.previous
resource "null_resource" "next" {
  depends_on = [time_sleep.wait_30_seconds]
}
```

Comment: To anyone watching this, the workaround has worked fine with a sleeper [set to 5min]. However it's much smoother when using azurerm_kubernetes_cluster resource. This gives you anyway more control of the cluster itself than using the rancher2_cluster resource. Tbh, I've now tried out the new v2 resource.

Answer (score 0):

@maes,

Can you please check out the following:

1. Verify the removal order, confirm that AKS deletion was never run before the vnet deletion.
2. If (1) is true, follow https://www.terraform.io/docs/cli/commands/graph.html to export and review the dependency graph. You should find a dependency from AKS to vnet.
3. If not, try depends_on following https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/terraform/dependencies#manage-explicit-dependencies.

Comment: Hey Srijit, Thank you for the reply. In the meantime, i've tried another route, which works much better. I guess it is an issue with the rancher2_provider, which does not wait until the cluster is destroyed. We have moved the cluster creation now to the azurerm_kubernetes_cluster provider and when we do a destroy, it recognizes the dependencies and deletes everything as it is expected.